# KnockoutJS selectedOptions binding causes select box to jitter in IE8

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is only in IE8, 
Occurs when I have a multiple values select box bound to 
observableArray with selectedOptions and there are more items than 
select can show (scrolling is enabled). 
So whenever I Ctrl+click the item in a select box the scrolling 
position 'jumps away' and I end up being scrolled down a bit. This 
produces a jittery unpleasant experience. 
As I understand it, this problems is because of two-way binding of 
selectedOptions: when I click on an item, it gets added to the array, 
which in turn causes the select box refill after observableArray 
notifies the UI of its changes. 
Is there anything that can be done?

UPDATE:

I ended up using this binding:

```
<select data-bind='visible:operator() ? operator().Element == "DropDown" : false, 
                                options: property() ? property().ReferenceItems : null, 
                                optionsText: "Name", 
                                optionsValue: "Id", 
                                optionsCaption: "Выберите...", 
                                selectedOptions: selectedValues,
                                multiple: selectedValues().length > 1'>
</select>
```

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same problem

Comment: @Mel, I ended up removing two-way binding, and used only one-way (from ui to  viewmodel). This solved my issue.

Comment: sorry, I'm quite new at this. but how exactly did you did this? I tried using plain js arrays and while it did remove the jitter problem, the array is not getting updated with the selection...

Comment: Sorry, it's been so long ago, I frankly don't remember the specifics. I pasted the code I found in the repo, maybe it'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know... all I can recommend is try asking this on the knockoutjs google group. It seems to be active and has folks who are experts responding to stuff like this.